# Alt+F4 stops working after compiz restart. How to fix?

Tags: unity, 14.04, gnome, keyboard, compiz

**Observation:** if I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `compiz --replace`, then the shorcut key <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> for closing windows stops working. I am using the latest version of gnome-ubuntu (14.04).

**Question:** Is there a way to restore the hotkey functionality? Or is there another way to restart `compiz` without losing the hotkey functionality? Also tell me, if this is a bug, then I'll try to report it! Also sometimes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd> stop working, but it seems to happen for a different reason which I have not found out yet. Therefore it would be nice to know how to restore/relaunch the keyboard functionality in general.

Unfortunately I have to restart `compiz` this way sometimes, because occasionally my mouse clicks will stop working (for whatever reason, but this is a different story), and the solution other people with the same problem have found is to restart `compiz`.

Comment: Does Ctrl+Q still work?

Comment: Take a look at the key configuration in `ccsm`: What is in "General options/Key bindings/Close window"?

Comment: @Tim Yes it does. I never used it before, though! Thanks.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel it says `<Alt>F4` before and after. However, if change that value to something else, and change it back to `<Alt>F4`, then it starts working again.

Comment: Oh, that really feels like a conflict between two programs binding the `<Alt>F4`...

Comment: I prefer Ctrl+Q, I can do it with 1 hand, and it feels nicer - Alt+F4 is a bit random to me. Do you have something like gimp, or an image editor open at the moment? Try closing everything and just try Alt+F4 on gedit.

Comment: With all windows of all programmes closed the problem still exists. There is no systematic way to check, if this key combination gets assigned to another programme, and if yes to whicht, is there?

Comment: did you try resetting the profile in CCSM- Preferences? That should remove all the conflicts. One more thing, do you have two or more ccsm type managers running simultaneously? If yes- then remove one of them from the startup.

Comment: I'm sorry to bring this up again but I thought I'd comment for anyone looking for it - the issue for me was that I had 2 instances of Compiz (sort of) - I had changed xfwm4 to compiz in /etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-session.xml *and* I had "compiz --replace" to run on startup in my XFCE settings. Removing the startup command means that compiz still runs and alt-f4 works from startup. Thank you for your comment in helping debugging this @VolkerSiegel

Comment: @QuickishFM There is nothing wrong with bringing it up again! It's useful information, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a bug.  Going into CCSM and toggling the Close Window key binding under General Options fixed it for me, but this is obviously not an ideal solution.

Comment: Same here with Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Here is the corresponding bug report by the way: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1292833

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour also can happen with `unity --replace`.

One possible solution is to check in whether commands are enable in CompizConfig Settings Manager (you may need to install it with `apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`).

Look for an option called 'Commands', in the 'General' category. In my case this was un-checked. I suspect these settings may have been used when restarting Unity/Compiz, though that doesn't explain how Alt-F4 worked at first, after logging in.

I'm using the Unity edition of Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 1):

To restart both Compiz and Unity open the terminal and type:

```
setsid compiz --replace    
setsid unity
```

After running these two commands the keyboard shortcuts will work normally (because of restarting Unity).

Comment: did not work for me on ubuntu 14.04. Neither alt f4 not control f4 work.